# How to setup tree cache in tc server

Tags: caching, infinispan, tcserver

I want to migrate an aplication which is currenty runnung in jboss 7 to tc server 2.9.6. In jboss we were using infinispan tree cache for caching. Is it possible to set up the same for tc server or I have to use any other caching techniques in tc server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrating projects from one container to another is often problematic. Not as much with Infinispan
This article(https://dzone.com/articles/how-configure-infinispan) is about configuring Infinispan, using Transaction Manager for demarcating transaction boundaries, while keeping the data both in a memory and relational database.